# Track Throughput changes Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to review if there is a way to track throughput changes for Azure Cosmos DB when using manual throughput. Please if you can provide any pointers.

Comment: Please edit your question to be specific, including relevant code and related issues. Currently this is a fairly broad requirement.

Comment: You can do this via an Alert triggered by Azure Monitoring or Diagnostics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-alerts#common-alerting-scenarios